# Alternatives to tableView.scrollToRow()

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

**Problem**

I need to have a UITableView reload with a specific cell positioned at the top of the tableview. For instance, have the 3rd cell in the tableView appear at the top of the tableView, rather than the 1st.

The issue in doing this comes from not being able to use the

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

function, because I have a custom header that expands and collapse when the user scrolls. That means when I call the scrollToRow() function, my header collapses, messing things up.

**Question**

Is there any way to have a tableView open/reload with the 3rd cell positioned at the top of the tableView without using a "scroll" function?

Thanks!

Comment: `rectForRow...` is what you need. That'll give you the actual origin to scroll to, including any insets, table header heights, and section header heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps to fulfill your requirement:

1. Identify **NSIndexPath** of one of the visible cells.
2. Get its **rectForRowAtIndexPath**.
3. Get the current **contentOffset** of the table, itself.
4. Or, you can use **scrollRectToVisible**

This is how we use `contentOffset`:

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(rectForRowAtIndexPath.point, animated: true)
```

And `scrollRectToVisible`:

```
mainTableView.scrollRectToVisible(rectForRowAtIndexPath.point, animated: true)
```

Comment: This works, but only if animated is set to true. When I set it to false, nothing happens. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ohhh! Strange :O